# Qt/C++ - Barcodes generated not readable

Tags: c++, c, qt, barcode

I have written a simple barcode generator in Qt5/C++ (Windows):

```
void BarcodeDialog::printBarcode(QString barcodeText)
{
    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/code128.ttf");
    QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
    QFont barcodefont = QFont("Code 128", 50, QFont::Normal);
    barcodefont.setLetterSpacing(QFont::AbsoluteSpacing,0.0);
    this->ui->label->setFont(barcodefont);
    this->ui->label->setText(barcodeText);
}
```

It generates the barcode, but the barcode scanner app on my android phone fails to read the generated barcode. What I am doing wrong in this case?

[image]

**Edit:**
The plain text needs some encoding. Refer to https://github.com/adamgiacomelli/Qt-barcode for code sample

Comment: Maybe you printer isn't good enough to print a barcode.  Do you have any way to post a high res slightly magnified image of the generated barcode.  I probably could tell if it is printed well enough.

Comment: @JSF I suppose it is clear from the code that I am printing it inside a QLabel and not on paper.

Comment: Are you trying to read the bar code directly from screen with the phone's cam? try printing it to paper and give it one more try. Some times phone cams are not good taking pictures from monitor front to front (I dont know the physical reason to this) some times weird stripes appear on the photos.

Comment: Deleted answer moved to comment (to help other people understanding the OP problem): See this interesting webpage: http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/articles/reading_barcodes_directly_from_computer_screen. You should find a working bar code (on google image for instance), print it on paper. If your Android app can scan it on paper but not on screen...you won't manage to make it work from your Qt app....if you did that and if you can scan barcode from screen, you may want to print the one you generated on paper and see if app can scan it from here or not (just to check)

Comment: Where do you add the check digit?  I assumed from the posted code it is added by the caller.  But now I assume you forgot entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code 128 has some requirements in addition to the string you want to display. It needs a start character, a check character, and a stop character. See your font documentation for the characters you need to insert in the string for the start and stop characters, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) for the check code algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is their any barcode font I can use for urls which doesn't need any special encoding/padding

Comment: @adnankamili you can use Code 39 instead, all it needs is an asterisk before and after the string.